# Titan multiple ID query

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

What is the **best** way to query Titan for a collection of vertices by a collection of id's?

Assume I have some nodes with UUID as a property, and I want to get those vertices by a collection of ids - what is the best method for querying?

I can loop over the id collection and get the desired vertices one by one - vertex by vertex with this API (in this example the userId is a my looped object over the id collection):

```
for(String userId: usersList) {     
    tg.getVertices("UUID", userId).iterator();
}
```

Or this one:

```
for(String userId: usersList) {    
    tg.query().has("UUID", userId).vercities().iterator();
}
```

but what I can't find is a way to give Titan the list and get in a single call,
what is the best way to do this in Java?

**EDIT**

In other words I'm looking for the equivalent way for the SQL `IN` operator - but in titan syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE City IN ('fe4e2e2c-8638-4081-b6de-e10252e638e7', 'fess2c-8638-4rgf-b6de-e102sdf3447');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Contains` predicate:

```
tg.query().has("UUID", Contains.IN, usersLists).verticies().iterator();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Titan 1.0 (thus TinkerPop 3.x) you can do this more directly with Gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', within('marko','josh'))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add it to index and then retrieve it as searching a graph via an iterator is not productive, if you think you are going to search on that field it is always better to add it to index.

Also use composite titan index for unique fields as it is much faster.

Another approach would be to partition your graph so that you know where to search it and then use an iterator.